# Going from web.xml to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic, web.xml, weblogic12c

I'm upgrading an existing application to use Spring Boot and to move away from web.xml.
While I've achieved functionality, there's a portion of my web.xml that for the life of me I cannot figure out how to upgrade to spring boot. (If it matters I'm using 1.5.6)

Relevant portion of my web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>basic</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Here's my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
         return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to determine how to set up anything to mirror the functionality of security-constraint or login-config using a code based approach.

If anyone has any ideas of how to or can point me in the right direction, I'd be greatly appreciative. A few hours of googling and trying solutions has left me with nothing.

Comment: Maybe look for a tutorial "spring boot security tutorial"? With this search term you find plenty of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `@EnableWebSecurity` and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

See example below:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```